# Curve fit in SPSS repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, spss, polynomial, psychology

I have cognitive data collected at 8 timepoints, which are 18 months apart. I would like to know what curve cognitive performance fits over time. I.e. is cognitive performance best explained by a linear, quadratic, cubic ... etc curve? My data is in wide format and due to the sheer number of variables I have, I am not keen to change it to narrow/long format.

How do I go about fitting curves in this manner on SPSS? I note that you can use the GLM repeated measures command and only include the within subjects variables (cognition/time) without any between-subjects factors and request polynomial contrasts. It looks like this tests curve for me. See screen shot.

To all those far better at statistics than me, is this an appropriate way to test whether cognition over time is linear/quadratic/cubic etc? If you feel this is not appropriate, could you explain why please?

[image: SPSS screenshot]

Comment: The relatively high p-values for all terms above the quadratic suggests the polynomial degree may be far too large, creating a gross overfitting.  High degree polynomials are almost always a poor choice when not indicated by a solid theoretical foundation.  Have you considered a spline?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable way to assess polynomial trends over time in means of variables. Graphing the data is always a good idea as well. Best of luck in interpreting a seventh-order polynomial.